# Facebook Post Images from local system on own Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

i have 1 dog page on Facebook,
i usually post photo of dogs when ever i have time, so trying to write a scheduler that will take images from my system folder and upload and publish on my page.

i want to post images, from my local system to 1 of my managed pages.
i have page access token. and using below curl i am getting response as well.

```
curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/page_id/photos?published=true' -H 'Cookie: ps_l=0; ps_n=0; ps_l=0; ps_n=0' -F 'access_token="my_page_access_toekn"' -F 'source=@"/C:/Users/Downloads/cute_dog.jpg"' -F 'publish="true"
```

and i am getting response back

```
{
    "id": "38868xxxxx",
    "post_id": "10326941xxxxx_388682220xxxxx"
}
```

when i login from my own account, i can see the images being posted on the page.
but when i login from my friend account, i don't see the image.
i tried adding `publish="true` in body as well as in path param, but nothing seems working.
for reference, i am following this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages-api/posts

what am i missing?